# Suggestion for New versions of TAILS

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'm sure there is a bettter place to put in suggestions for future releases of TAILS but I haven't found out where to do so. Forgive the ignorance on my part. I would like to make 2 suggestions;

1) Add to the standard set of applications and GUI application for creating bootable USB drives similar in function to Unetbootin. You already have a CD burn utility, but newer laptops are being produced without CD drives now, and as we all know, the utility of live linux distributions is invaluable.

2) Although it does reduce the anonymity of TAILS, there are some applications in which the use of persistent storage is vital. In these cases, function may very well take precedence over anonymity while the security of TAILS is still of utmost importance and can't be compromised. In this case, being able to make TAILS customizable in it's persistence, that is, *all* changes to the desktop, programs and directories are persistent, should be an option albeit one that carries appropriate warnings as persistence currently does. I changed the desktop to the one that has the Debian background, and added a toolbar to the browser and music to the music folder to discover that even with persistence those things did not get saved.

Job well done to the team! Thank you so much for such a wonderful suite of tools for the community to use to make the use of the internet so much more safe.

Regards, Harold

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Tails Support Page](https://tails.boum.org/support/index.en.html), you can search existing feature requests and add new ones [here](https://labs.riseup.net/code/projects/tails/issues?query_id=108).